# Como se podría insertar una pagina externa como nuevo recurso de otro url?

Tags: wordpress, web, url, frontend

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web con Wordpress pero la sección de noticias fue trabajada en un WordPress aparte, quiero que el al hacer click del hipervínculo de esta, el url no sea distinto, sino que mas bien, este se muestre como un recurso mas del url principal.

Comment: podrías proporcionar un ejemplo de url y de "un recurso mas del url principal" ?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que lo que buscas es tener esa pagina en una sección de la tuya, para eso podrias usar la etiqueta html [Iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

```html
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    title="Inline Frame Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
</iframe>
```

esto es muy usado para cargar mapas y etc.